# How to get the hot item name and path from Explorer?

Tags: shell, explorer

It was easy when the Windows' explorer was using a SysListView32 control for displaying its files list as opposed to the DirectUIHWND control in the subsequent versions of Windows after XP.

A simple task such as obtaining the 'hot item' which is that item (a filename) the mouse hovers above for some hundreds of milliseconds, where before I could use the macros

ListView_GetHotItem with ListView_GetItemText and be able to obtain the filename under the mouse cursor.

This simple task becomes almost impossible to do with the DirectUIHWND window unless I revert this control back to a
SysListView32 which I have seen being proposed as the only solution on the many sites I have searched, and even if used the change does not occur immediately but only after I navigate out of the folder first.

It has taken me almost 2 years trying to find a solution to this and until now I feel stumped.

Anyone any idea please ?

Basically I have subclassed the parent of the tooltip and intercepted the tooltip notifications and all I need is the filename and the full path of the item the mouse hoovers above it, the hot item.

Comment: Subsequent query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73487788/infotip-shell-extension

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2000/march/windows-2000-ui-innovations-enhance-your-user-s-experience-with-new-infotip-and-icon-overlay-shell-extensions

IQueryInfo is required to provide the runtime text to the shell. IPersistFile is used by Explorer to let the extension know about the specific file currently under the mouse pointer.